# Azure B2C show custom error message based on the the errorCode using CustomPolicy

Tags: azure, rest, azure-ad-b2c

We have the Azure custom policy set up. whenever the user registers we validate the information the user provided. if there is an issue API returns an `erroCode` and `message`.
the message is shown bellow.

[image]

[image]

response from the API.

```
{
  "status":"400",
  "errorCode":"2013",
  "message":"Parece que você já tem uma conta. Faça o login."
}
```

I want to show a custom message based on the `errorCode`. how can I achieve this( preferably without using JavaScript)? also I can switch the `errorCode` with the `message`.

someone answered the question here
[Localised message for RestAPI error response in B2C custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788906/localised-message-for-restapi-error-response-in-b2c-custom-policy)
but I cant make head and tails of his answer.